# Dynamically use both python raw_input and raw_input().split()

Tags: python-2.7, stdout, stdin

The input format is:

```
6
1
2 5
2 7
2 9
1
1
```

Input:

First line contains an integer Q, the number of queries. Q lines follow.
A Type-1 ( Customer) Query, is indicated by a single integer 1 in the line.
A Type-2 ( Chef) Query, is indicated by two space separated integers 2 and C (cost of the package prepared) .

I want to read the input from `stdin` console and here is my code

```
n = int(input())

stack1 = []
for i in range(n):
    x = input()
    x = int(x)
if x == 2:
    y = input()
    stack1.append(y)
elif x == 1:
    length = len(stack1)
    if length > 0:
        print(stack1.pop())
    else:
        print("No Food")
```

I have tried `x,y = raw_input().split()` this statement also fails because sometimes input has single value. Let us know how to read the defined input from `stdin` ???

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? You're not using both.

Comment: i am using Python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use len() to find length of string based on that change your stdin.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    s = input()
    if(len(s) > 1):
        x,y = s.split()
        x = int(x)
    else:
        x = int(s)
    print(x)
```

Cheers.